# Regular Expression break down URL into parts

Tags: regex

I've just recently started learning Regex so i'm not sure yet about a couple of aspects of the hole thing.

Right now my web page reads in the URL breaks it up into parts and only uses certain parts for processing: 
E.g. 1) http://mycontoso.com/products/luggage/selloBag
E.g. 2) http://mycontoso.com/products/luggage/selloBag.sf404.aspx

For some reason Sitefinity is giving us both possibilities, which is fine, but what I need from this is only the actual product details as in "luggage/selloBag"

My current Regex expression is: `"(.*)(map-search)(\/)(.*)(\.sf404\.aspx)"`, I combine this with a replace statement and extract the contents of group 4 (or $4), which is fine, but it doesn't work for example 2.

So the question is: Is it possible to match 2 possibilities with regular expressions where a part of a string might or might not be there and then still reference a group whose value you actually want to use?

Answer (score 5):

RFC-3986 is the authority regarding URIs. [Appendix B](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-B) provides this regex to break one down into its components:

```py
re_3986 = r"^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?"
# Where:
# scheme    = $2
# authority = $4
# path      = $5
# query     = $7
# fragment  = $9
```

Here is an enhanced (and commented) regex (in Python syntax) which utilizes named capture groups:

```py
    re_3986_enhanced = re.compile(r"""
        # Parse and capture RFC-3986 Generic URI components.
        ^                                    # anchor to beginning of string
        (?:  (?P<scheme>    [^:/?#\s]+): )?  # capture optional scheme
        (?://(?P<authority>  [^/?#\s]*)  )?  # capture optional authority
             (?P<path>        [^?#\s]*)      # capture required path
        (?:\?(?P<query>        [^#\s]*)  )?  # capture optional query
        (?:\#(?P<fragment>      [^\s]*)  )?  # capture optional fragment
        $                                    # anchor to end of string
        """, re.MULTILINE | re.VERBOSE)
```

For more information regarding the picking apart and validation of a URI according to RFC-3986, you may want to take a look at an article I've been working on: [Regular Expression URI Validation](http://jmrware.com/articles/2009/uri_regexp/URI_regex.html)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your regex implementation, but most support a syntax like

```
(\.sf404\.aspx|)
```

Assuming that's your group 4 (i.e. zero-indexed groups). The `|` lists two alternatives, one of which is the empty string.

Comment: how do you combine it into one regular expressions that accepts the URI whether it has the sf404.aspx or not. More importantly I'll be doing a replace in which case I want the sf404.aspx portion remove 'if' it is there, or do nothing if it isn't.

Comment: @Jacques: for combining this in a full URI RE, see ridgerunner's answer. For search and replace: replace the contents of this group with the empty string. When `sf404.aspx` is not there, you'll be replacing nothing with nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say if you're doing this in javascript, but if you are, the `parseUri` lib written by Steven  Levithan does a pretty damn good job at parsing urls. You can get it from various places, including [here](http://javascript.internet.com/snippets/parseuri.html) (click on the "Source Code" tab) and [here](http://snipplr.com/view/29397/parseuri-12-split-urls-in-javascript/).